# How do I deal with multiple predicates?

Tags: sparql, rdf

My goal is to write a SPARQL query to determine all the smartphone units whose operating system (`s:OS`) is Android and whose price is less than 400.

It's confusing because in Turtle format, there are multiple predicates. There is `s:OS` but also `rdf:type`. Which do I use?

I have the following but I'm unsure about its accuracy:

```
SELECT ?phone
WHERE {
?phone s:OS|rdf:type ?OS .
?OS rdfs:subClassOf s:Android .

?phone s:price ?price .
FILTER (?price < 400) .
}
```

Comment: Looks OK. Probably you could also try `?phone (s:OS|rdf:type)/(rdfs:subClassOf*) s:Android`. Or show your data.

Comment: Looks to me like your data is broken, as the `rdf:type` of a phone should be something like `http://www.productontology.org/id/Smartphone` or `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Device`, while the `rdf:type` of `s:Android` should be something like `http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/OperatingSystem106568134` or `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Software`. (What does your `s:` prefix expand to?)